# Travelling through USA with double nationality

Tags: usa, schengen, dual-nationality, mexico, austria

My children are holding dual citizenship - Mexico and Austria. We are currently in Mexico and will travel back to Austria with a flight from Mexico City to Miami and from there to Schengen (Madrid) with final stop Vienna.
My children entered Mexico with their Mexican passport, as this is required by law.
I'm currently wondering how to correctly travel through the USA, since they don't have a US visa for their Mexican passport, but can travel with ESTA only using their Austrian passport.
They will obviously show their Mexican passport on leaving Mexico. But with what passport should they do the check-in to the flight? I want to use the Austrian one, since ESTA. But won't the airline/mexican migration check check for the migration stamp? Will the US migration deny them entry based on this situation?
I could not find information for this situation online, since everything is centered around having dual citizenship between US and another country. Unfortunately the consulate and embassy hotline only guide me to their respective web pages.

Comment: Airline (API, check-in, boarding), US passport control, Schengen passport control: Austrian passport. Mexican exit controls: Mexican passport.

Comment: The advice given in the duplicate question is correct, but your case is fortunately fairly simple one, as [Mexico allows dual citizenship](https://www.gob.mx/sre/documentos/double-nationality), and so does Austria [if the other citizenship was acquired at birth](https://www.bmeia.gv.at/en/travel-stay/living-abroad/citizenship-and-union-citizenship/dual-citizenship), so you can just show both passports to anybody who has a problem.

Comment: "won't the airline check check for the migration stamp?": Probably not; they're mostly just concerned with the visa or ESTA to enter the US.  But if they want to see evidence of your entry just show the Mexican passport.  "won't the airline/mexican migration check check for the migration stamp?": Always show the Mexican passport to Mexican officers.  This saves them the trouble of wondering whether you've overstayed.  They shouldn't care whether there's a stamp.

Comment: "Will the US migration deny them entry based on this situation?": If they have a valid ESTA on a valid Austrian passport then they won't deny them entry for lack of documentation.  It doesn't matter that they used a Mexican passport to enter Mexico (or anywhere else).  The simplest thing to do is always to declare the same nationality to officials of the same country, but there's no harm in showing both passports and saying "I'm a dual citizen" if a question arises.)